# AngularJS: How to call function on onsubmit inside the controller as ng-submit

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing mobile app in angularJS, ionic framework and cordova. I am having a scenario where form data i am submitting to server and when server respond me with the status as 200 i am navigating user to the confirmation page. My code is:

```
<ion-view title="Fill the Form" ng-controller="formSubmit">
<ion-content class="padding-vertical" ng-repeat="htmlValue in HTML">
    <form name="fieldForm" id="{{htmlValue.Id}}" method="post" onsubmit="submitFormData($(this).serialize(), $(this).attr('id'))">
        <div class="bootstrap" ng-bind-html="htmlValue.Html | unsafe">

        </div>
        <div class="padding">
            <button  class="button button-block button-calm">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</ion-content>
```

The function i have written below the index.html page before the body ends.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitFormData(serializedData,value){
        var data = serializedData;
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url+"put/putFormFilledRawData.php?id="+value,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(tableData){
                alert('success');
            }});
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

Thing is when response arrives as 200 i have to navigate through $state.go() function and for that this function needs to be accessed inside the controller. For that i tried ng-submit at the place of onsubmit but is always shows me error: `submitFormData` is not a function. How to make it work inside controller from front view forms submit call?

Comment: You need to bind submitFormData function with $scope like $scope.submitFormData  = function() {......}

Comment: There is actually to much jQuery for this to works. You should take a look about controllers and scope in angular to do this. You shoudn't use $.ajax but $http angular service, you shoudn't use $.attr and $.serialize but you should use angular binding instead.

Comment: How do i get the data that is filled inside the form. Note that form is dynamic so the data can not be captured in static way and sent to post request. what is the replacement of $(this).serialize in angularJS?

Answer (score 4):

The more angular way of doing it is following:

HTML :

```
    <ion-view title="Fill the Form" ng-controller="formSubmit">
    <ion-content class="padding-vertical" ng-repeat="htmlValue in HTML">
        <form name="fieldForm" id="{{htmlValue.Id}}" ng-submit="submitFormData(htmlValue)">
            <div class="bootstrap" ng-bind-html="htmlValue.Html | unsafe">

            </div>
            <div class="padding">
                <button  class="button button-block button-calm">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Controller :

```
angular.module('formSubmitModule', [])
        .controller('formSubmit', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
          $scope.HTML = []; //Assuming you are getting the array of objects here


    $scope.submitFormData= function(formObj) {
$http({
    url: '/someUrl', 
    method: "POST",
    params: {paramA: valueA, paramB: valueB}
 });
};
```

(Another flavour of $http service to pass the params in the URL)

This is how you should be making the ajax call and POST the form data in angularJS.

P.S. You can also explore the 'promises' that are returned by the $http service of the angularjs rather then dealing with success and error callbacks.

Comment: how can i use the posted data inside the form which i am showing using ng-bind-html="htmlValue.Html | unsafe" that i am getting with $(this).serialize() if i have to use ng-submit?

Comment: You dont even have to serialize the form object. $http service does take care of the json data-type object. Just pass the complete object in the $http service.

Comment: i want to send the data to my server in serialize format like key1=value&key2=value2&key3=value3....like wise. How can i achieve that just that is remaining otherwise your answer is perfect one

Comment: Use $http service as following :

$http({
    url: /someURL, 
    method: "POST",
    params: {paramA: 'A', paramB : 'B'}
 });

Comment: My friend that is what my concern. PI even dont know the paramA & paramB. the form inupt names are defined at the type of creating the form and it is dynamic. So i will not be knowing what is the paramA & paramB infact there may bee 100 of input fields..... I just want to post the data to the server in serialize format when form will get submit. how can i capture that in angularJS?. In php i usually write action="url" and the data will be posted to the url how do i capture the same in angularJS. at my server side PHP is there so no issue. Just i need to serialize data

Comment: If there can be 100's of parameters then you should not be providing them in the URL, instead POST it in the body of the RESTfull call.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation of [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit)

You need to create a controller or a directive and bind the function to the $scope.

Comment: your submit method needs to be in the formSubmit controller. Can you post the code of the 'formSubmit' controller you defined in the ng-controller tag? like @Mico did

Comment: okk.. but i am not getting the posted data. I need that one in serialized format. not i am getting even the if. I am using ng-submit so jquery is not working here

Answer (score 3):

Check below example

```
<script>
    angular.module('submitExample', [])
        .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.list = [];
          $scope.text = 'hello';
          $scope.submit = function() {
            if ($scope.text) {
              $scope.list.push(this.text);
              $scope.text = '';
            }
          };
        }]);
    </script>


<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
</form>
```

Comment: look the for is dynamic one i don't have any idea with whatever fields and what type of fields it will contain. That is why i have used serialize() function

Comment: this is copied and pasted from the angular documentation for ng-submit: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: Is there something we can't copied if he required a solution so i just provided